# Custom MsBuild Task fails with assembly loading errors

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, msbuild-task

I have defined a custom MSBuild Task, using .netcore 5.0 and it is accessible [here](https://github.com/persiandeveloper/custom-build-task).

The "Application" project uses "SnykTaskFile" in its build process.

When I build "Application" I got the following error :

> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Diagnostics.Process, Version=5.0.0.0,

If I remove the following code from "SnykTaskFile" :

```
    var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    processInfo.FileName = "cmd";
    processInfo.WorkingDirectory = Location;
    Process.Start(processInfo);
```

And build the "Application" again, it builds successfully, however if I have a logic around "Location" :

```
  if (Location.Contains("...."))
      {
          return false;
      }
```

It throws another error :

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0,

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/459914/custom-buld-task-when-used-in-csproject-throws-39c.html?childToView=470025#answer-470025) and the discussion "Custom Tasks don't work with NET5.0" in git hub, it seems I should use netstandard 2.0 for task project type.